# Changed MAC address and now internet isn't working and I can't get on my router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Everything was working fine and I was poking around in the router settings and clicked the `Clone Mac Address` button to see what it did and hit Apply.

Now the internet isn't working (on the neighbor's internet) and I can't even get back on the router (`192.168.1.1`)

I reset the router but it still isn't working.

I have an `ASUS Wireless Router RT-N66R`.

Thanks.

Edit: I got back on the router but now my wireless MAC address is the same as the LAN MAC address. I think this is what the cloning did. Is there any way to find my old MAC address?

The section is titled `Special Requirement from ISP` so I think I may need to use a certain MAC address but I don't remember what the old one was. Is it possible to find that out without calling my ISP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check on the back of router..its MAC address is usually printed on it.

Comment: Okay I'll try that and see if it works. Do ISPs typically only allow you to use your router's default given MAC address? Why would changing it change anything?

Answer (score 0):

We'll, if you cannot connect to the router at all, I'd recommend resetting it to factory settings (this should disable MAC the cloning as well).

If you can connect to the router itself (disconnect from any other network, switch on and then attempt to connect with any terminal (be it PC or mobile browser) to disable the cloning).